# how ReadOnlyDictionary from .net 4.5 does not expose .Add method ? (not why)

Tags: .net, .net-4.5

I am curious how is it possible that `ReadOnlyDictionary` implements `IDictionary` and `ICollection` but it does not expose the methods `Add(TKey key, TValue value)`

```
ReadOnlyDictionary<object, object> dictionary;
dictionary.Add(null, null); // compilation error 

IDictionary<object,object> i;
i = dictionary;
i.Add(null, null);// no compilation error
```

Comment: Look up "explicit interface implementation" in your favorite C# language book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReadOnlyDictionary` [explicitly implements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173157.aspx) the Add methods (both in generic and non-generic form). Something like this:

```
void IDictionary.Add(Object key, Object value)
```

You can call it if you cast it to an `IDictionary`, but it will throw a NotSupportedException [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712730.aspx).